# Optional parameters in thymeleaf url

Tags: thymeleaf

I am generating a url in thymeleaf using the following code.

```
@{/schedule/data/bookableTimes/{teacherUsername}(teacherUsername=${teacher.user.username},lessonLengthType=${lessonLengthType},studentId=${#httpServletRequest.getParameter('studentId')})}
```

This works perfectly, when the studentId is supplied. However I also want to cater for the scenario when the studentId is not supplied.
Currently if the studentId is not supplied it will generate a url like so

```
/schedule/data/bookableTimes/teacher?lessonLengthType=full&studentId=
```

However this is not what I want, in the case that the studentId is null, I'd rather not have the studentId portion of the url generated at all. Is there a simple way to do this using thymeleaf?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43174870/1901067

Answer (score 1):

I would create a string and concatenate some part something like

```
string url ="/schedule/data/bookableTimes/";
if (teacherUser) url.add(teacher)
if (studentId) url.add(studentId)
@{*url}
```

Comment: Hi David, do you mean doing this in the Controller? I guess I could do that, but it's not quite the solution I was hoping for.

Comment: Don't need to You can do it purely in Thymeleaf. Where do you want to do it exactly?