# Conditions in Thymeleaf th:href parameter

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

So I have an element in my Thymeleaf template which has a link looking like that:

```
th:href="@{'/search/'+${searchType}(parameter1=${parameter1}, ... parameter10=${parameter10})}"
```

According to the current implementation the `parameter1...10` can have values that I don't want to include in the `href`. For example, if it's id, it can be -1, which means that no id chosen, so this parameter have to be omitted to avoid clattering the url string, so instead of

`/search/type?parameter1=-1`

get just clean

`/search/type`

How this can be achieved?
I tried this:

```
th:href="@{'/search/'+${searchType}((${parameter1}=='-1'?''parameter1=${parameter1}))}"
```

But this expression causes exception:

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse
>   as expression:

I tried this:

```
th:href="@{'/search/'+${searchType}(parameter1=(${parameter1}=='-1'?'':${parameter1}))}"
```

But then the result is still not acceptable:

`/search/type?parameter1=`

So what is the correct way to eliminate undesirable parameters from the url?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like I did more research and found a way.
The key word is: preprocessing.
[This is the link.](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Conditional-parameter-in-th-href-td4026083.html)
So for my purposes the following expression works:

```
th:href="@{'/search/'+${searchType}(__(${parameter1}=='-1'?','parameter1=${parameter1})__,__(${parameter2}=='-1'?','parameter2=${parameter2})__)}"
```

Short explanation: surround the expression with double underscores `__(${parameter1}=='-1'?','parameter1=${parameter1})__`, and then the surrounded expression will only be added if it evaluates to non-empty string. In the case of url parameters `','` evaluates to two empty parameters and not added.

Comment: Here is the link to the documentation: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing (the one in the linked forum is outdated)