# Ignore empty params in href in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

So I have this href:

```html
th:href="@{/apps/role/{pathVar}(pathVar=${var.attribute}, search=${param.search})}"
```

Which works fine, but I want to make the url look cleaner by hiding the search param, if it is empty.

**E.g.:**

- param.search = 'test' => url = `"../apps/role/varAttr?search=test"`
- param.search = '' => url = `"../apps/role/varAttr"`

I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43174524/conditions-in-thymeleaf-thhref-parameter) post, however nothing I tried could make it work for my purposes. It could be that the **`pathvariable`** has something to do with it, but really I'm clueless.

**I tried:**

```html
th:href="@{/apps/role/{pathVar}(pathVar=${var.attribute}, __(${param.search}=''?','search=${param.search})__)}
```

```html
th:href="@{/apps/role/{pathVar}(pathVar=${var.attribute}, __(${param.search}=''?,search=${param.search})__)}
```

as well as some more desperate attempts.

**Edit:** I use Thymeleaf version 3.0.11.

**Solution:**
The marked solution, didn't exactly work for me, but this did.
I just left out the first pair of `"__"` for the pathVar.

```
th:with="search=${param.search}"
th:href="@{/apps/role/{pathVar}(pathVar=${var.attribute}, __(${#strings.isEmpty(search)} ? '' : ('search=' + ${search}))__)}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```html
<a th:with="search=${param.search}"
   th:href="@{/apps/role/__${pathVar}__(pathVar=${var.attribute}, __(${#strings.isEmpty(search)} ? '' : ('search=' + ${search}))__)}">
   Click Url
</a>
```

---

If the `search` parameter **does not exist or is empty**, it will not add it. I did this with **`Thymeleaf` version 3.0.12.*